# How to ignore/remove property from spring.factories file from predefined jar?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, meta-inf

I have created custom SpringApplicationRunListener and added in Meta-INF of project file as org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener=
com.dt.testExec

Now,i want to ignore the pre defined property inside .m2/local/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.1.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE-sources.jar!/META-INF/spring.factories

org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener=
org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener

As, when i am running the project, 2 runListener are coming when context gets loaded but i want my custom one i.e "testExec" and not EventPublishingRunListener ?

Or any other way to remove/stop this "EventPublishingRunListener" from "List listeners" when project gets started?

It would be great if anyone can help.

Comment: First question: Why do you use such an old spring boot version? And no can not simply remove predefined factories... because those jar files are build by the Spring Team... ?

Comment: @khmarbaise because the above version was already used in the project.Any other way possible to remove the EventPublishingRunListener?.Since it causing issue in the project.

Comment: Really ? In which way because it's by default part of spring...the question is why is it causing issues... Also I would strongly recommend to upgrade as soon as possible...

Comment: @khmarbaise Actually i want to add executor in SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster as some listener is causing exception and stopping the complete application.So i figured out that it is called by EventPublishingRunListener(Read Only file).Therefore, i created new custom listener with executor and added in springRun listener.Now, this EventPublishingRunListener is also calling SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster which is causing issue.